# Repeated subclasses of ndb properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have create a subclass of `ndb.KeyProperty` that can accept keys, but also entities or base 64 key strings and convert them to keys. It works great, except when I try create a `repeated` property.

Basically my code is this:

```
def to_key(target):
    if isinstance(target, ndb.Model):
        target_key = target.key
    elif isinstance(target, ndb.Key):
        target_key = target
    else:
        try:
            target_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=target)
        except:
            raise TypeError('%s is not an ndb instance or key' % target)
    return target_key

class AutoKeyProperty(ndb.KeyProperty):
    def _validate(self, value):
        return to_key(value)
```

Handling iterable values in `_validate` just moves to the problem down to the base `ndb.KeyProperty` class.

Answer (score 0):

The right function you need to override is `_to_base_type`. This function convert an input value into an instance of property's type, in your case a Key. So your `AutoKeyProperty` class would look like this:

```
class AutoKeyProperty(ndb.KeyProperty):
    def _to_base_type(self, value):
        return to_key(value)
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to check this until now.I wanted to create a gist to show why the above doesn't work, but even using my own code from above, it works correctly now. No idea what changed, except perhaps SDK 1.8.6.